# Grails 2.0 and servletContext

Tags: grails, servlets, grails-2.0

I'm trying to access servletContextin a controller like so, but keep getting null pointer exception:

```
def servletContext = getServletContext()
def serverPath  = servletContext.getRealPath("/")
```

... I've come across that issue on mailing lists once just recently, but the only 'proper' workaround suggested was to set it in the init closure in BootStrap.groovy:

```
   import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder as SCH

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->

         SCH.servletContext = servletContext
    }
....
```

... is this still the case? That solution didn't make any difference for me, still got NPE

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`servletContext` is a spring bean that will automatically be injected if you declare `def servletContext` in your controller.

The holder objects are going away.  The recommended way to get a hold of the ServletContext or the ApplicationContext is through the `grailsApplication` spring bean.  For situations where you can't access `grailsApplication` (e.g. static methods), you can create your own holder classes.

Burt Beckwith wrote up a couple of great blog posts on the topic: [Accessing the GrailsApplication and ApplicationContext from domain classes without holders](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=993) and [Create your own Grails holder class](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1017).

Comment: ... hmmm, so I tried this:     def servletContext

    def p = servletContext.getRealPath('/') in a controller and I get "Cannot invoke method getRealPath() on null object", why would that be?

Comment: servletContext must declared as a field, not a local variable i.e. outside your action closure/method.